# How include line breaks in mustache values?

Tags: mustache

My mustache tag in a text file is e.g. "{{foo}}".
The value I am passing has an embedded newline: "aaaa\nbbbb".
The behavior I want is for the output to have:

```
aaaa
bbbb
```

But instead, it is

```
aaaa&#10;bbbb
```

How can I generate the newline in the output?

Answer (score 5):

I discovered that using {{{foo}}}  (3 nested braces) fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to your own question. Even 6 years later, it helped me!